# Spring Data MongoDB Unique Embedded Fields

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

So, I have one `@Document` class which has a embedded pojo field which I want it to be unique for the document based on a `key` in the pojo class. I tried using `@CompoundIndex` & `@Indexed` to mark it as unique but it doesn't seem to work.

```
@Document
public class Project {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Details> details = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Details{
    private String key;
    private String description;
}
```

What I want to achieve is that a `project` document should have unique `details` field in it with it's `key` being unique. But when I have the 
`@CompoundIndexes({ @CompoundIndex(name = "details_key", def = "{'details.key':1}", unique = true) })` on the `Project` class it doesn't work. Which I thought it should. Or am I wrong somewhere with my understanding. As I am new to this.

Comment: isnt @Id on Details.key enough?

Comment: @Deepak - Are you able to solve this issue ? Could you please  guide here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61948943/spring-data-mongo-apply-unique-combination-fields-in-embedded-document